# Consumir dados de um web service externo, como instanciar as class depois do "import" do WSDL?

Tags: php, java, web-service, wsdl

Eu não tenho conhecimentos em `WEB-SERVICES`, sendo esta a primeira vez que estou a usar.

Depois de muita pesquisa já consegui "importar" o ficheiro WSDL para o java e com isso "mapear" todas as classes do `Web-Service`, mas isso criou me muitas classes e agora nao sei quais usar.

O `web-service` foi desenvolvido em `PHP` com o `NuSOAP`, e penso que usa uma tecnologia antiga, algo como `JAX-RPC STYLE`(tive de instalar o plugin no netbeans para conseguir fazer esse mapeamento).

Agora no web-service tenho por exemplo esta função:

> Lista_produtos

**Como consigo listar esses produtos?**

*Classes que tenho referentes a isso:*

```
Lista_produtos.java
Lista_produtos_SOAPBUiler.java
Lista_produtos_SOAPserializer.java
RealtimeWebService.java//Penso que são as class principais
RealtimeWebService_Impl.java//Penso que são as class principais
RealtimeWebServicePortType.java
RealtimeWebServicePortTypeLista_produtosRequestStruct.java
RealtimeWebServicePortTypeLista_produtosRequestStruct_SOAPBuiler.java
RealtimeWebServicePortTypeLista_produtosRequestStruct_SOAPSerializer.java
```

Pelo nome dá para me indicar como devo fazer? Isto é, normalmente é generico ou depende da implementação de cada WSDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minha grande duvida era a como instanciar as class, e entao ficaria assim:

```
RealtimeWebServicePortType ws = new RealtimeWebService_Impl().getRealtimeWebServicePort();
ws.lista_linhas();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende da forma que você traduz as definições do WSDL. Usando o wsimport, é muito comum que várias classes sejam geradas, não se preocupe com isso, cada classe equivale a uma estrutura importante do wsdl que foi gerado pelo PHP.

Para utilizar os serviços, você deve instanciar a classe que herda de Service e em seguida chamar o método que retorna a interface com os métodos listados no serviço. No seu caso, parece ser:

```
RealtimeWebService_Impl serviceFactory = new RealtimeWebService_Impl();
RealtimeWebService service = serviceFactory.get..Port(); // Algum método que termine com port e, que retorna a interface com os métodos disponibilizados no serviço.
```

Depois que você obter a instância do service, você pode chamar os serviços disponíveis.

Lembre-se de tratar as possíveis exceções que podem surgir na hora de obter a conexão, é comum que o serviço esteja indisponível e isso pode causar erros na sua aplicação.

Comment: Não, assim não funciona, certamente devido a maneira como foi construído o `WSDL`, mas felizmente já resolvi o problema, contudo obrigado a mesma.

Comment: Consegue sim, eu já implementei um serviço em NuSOAP e o consumi em java dessa forma.O erro que deu pra você pode ter sido por outros motivos. Talvez o WSDL gerado seja de uma especificação mais antiga do SOAP(muda de acordo com a versão do nusoap), etc...Não consigo comentar em cima desse seu comentário, sem saber, especificamente, qual o problema que deu.